# How do I accept a duel challenge from a friend?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

I started playing Yugioh Duel Links and got through the tutorial stage pretty quickly. I reached Stage 2 and then received a friend request shortly followed by a duel challenge. The message appear on the top of my phone a few times, but it did not give me an option to accept the duel. I browsed through my friend's list and menu with no option to accept the duel either.

How do I accept a duel challenge from a friend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting at Stage 4, you will be able to access the PvP Arena, where you will be able to duel other players. Go to the "PvP Arena" section of the game in the bottom menu, and then select "Friend Duels".

[image]

You will have there the list of all the challenges you have received from the other players. Select the challenge you are looking for, and then select "Start PvP Duel". The duel will then start if everything is going well.